# Who made Mjölnir?

Tags: norse, god-items, thor, weapons

The God Thor, in many stories I have been exposed to, has a hammer called Mjölnir that provides superpowers. In some versions of stories the powers are stronger then a God alone.

Where did Mjölnir come from? Who made it, or how was it made?

Comment: This is fairly simple question, there is an answer in the header of the [Wikipedia article Mjölnir](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mj%C3%B6lnir).  There has been some comments in Meta about discouraging questions who's answer can easily be found online.  If you feel strongly that this question is to simple for this site, please open a Meta discussion about it.

Answer (score 9):

Direct quote from the wikipedia article of [Mjölnir](http://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mj%C3%B6lnir)

> hammer of [Thor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thor), a major Norse god associated with thunder. [Mjölnir](http://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mj%C3%B6lnir) is depicted in Norse mythology as one of the most fearsome weapons, capable of leveling mountains. In his account of Norse mythology, Snorri Sturluson relates how the hammer was made by the dwarven brothers [Sindri](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eitri) and [Brokkr](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brokkr), and how its characteristically short handle was due to a mishap during its manufacture.

As to how it's made it is said on the wiki that it was made as a bet to show Loki that they could make a item more beautiful than those of the Sons of Ivaldi. Although they didn't intend to make the handle as short as it is. the reason for that is that Loki did not intend to let them win and therefor tried to hinder them during forging.

> Finally, Sindri puts some iron in the forge and tells Brokkr not to stop pumping the bellows. Loki comes a third time and this time bites Brokkr on the eyelid even harder. The bite is so deep that it draws blood. The blood runs into Brokkr's eyes and forces him stop working the bellows just long enough to wipe his eyes. This time, when Sindri returns, he takes Mjöllnir out of the forge. The handle is shorter than Sindri had planned and so the hammer can only be wielded with one hand.

And as to how [Thor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thor) got [Mjölnir](http://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mj%C3%B6lnir) if my memory isn't wrong then it was because [Mjölnir](http://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mj%C3%B6lnir) was given to [Odin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Odin) as a gift. When [Odin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Odin) found out that [Mjölnir](http://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mj%C3%B6lnir) deemed [Thor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thor) worthy to wield him [Odin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Odin) gave [Mjölnir](http://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mj%C3%B6lnir) to [Thor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thor). For he him self didn't need the hammer.

Comment: This question is much improved from it's original version, good job :) but it relies entirely on Wikipedia for reference.  The optimal answer would have supporting references from other sources.

Comment: That is true but I'm not one who knows all kinds of mythology sources and reffrences. If someone is to suggest a good edit ill accept it but unfortunately this is kind of my extend. :(

Comment: @maam27, the Wikipedia does reference Skáldskaparmál 43. (See solsdottir's answer below.) Wikipedia rules require references for information not considered common knowledge, so you can usually get to the source material from the Wikipedia citations.

Answer (score 6):

If you look in Faulkes' translation of the Poetic Edda the story can be found on pp. 96-7, in the section of Skaldskaparmal that explains kennings for gold. The story begins when Loki cuts off the hair of Thor's wife Sif and has to appease the angry thunder-god. ([A link](http://www.sacred-texts.com/neu/pre/pre05.htm) to another translation. Scroll down to section XXXV.)

Loki goes to the sons of Ivalde, who make golden hair for Sif and treasures for Odin and Freyr. That was fine, but then he bets [Brokk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brokkr) and Sindri they can't make better things, and wagers his head that they can't. He turns himself into a fly to hinder them, which is why Mjollnir has a short handle, as maam27's quote from Wikipedia relates.

Characteristically, Loki gets out of the wager by saying the dwarves can have his head as long as they don't cut his neck. (Shades of the [Merchant of Venice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Merchant_of_Venice).) They content themselves with sewing his mouth shut, a fitting punishment.